# How to override default schema validation messages

Tags: mongodb, go

I have to translate the default model validation messages in database layer, so I was thinking of a "proper way" to do this by default when using usual collection functions (such as `InsertOne()`, `InsertMany()`, etc.

Thus, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/_examples/translations/main.go) I created a file called `locales/es.go` with the following code:

```golang
package locales

import (
    "github.com/go-playground/locales/es"
    ut "github.com/go-playground/universal-translator"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    es_translations "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10/translations/es"
)

var (
    uni      *ut.UniversalTranslator
    validate *validator.Validate
)

/**
 * Registra las traducciones de los esquemas de MongoDB.
 */
func SetupLocales() {
    es := es.New()
    uni := ut.New(es, es)

    trans, _ := uni.GetTranslator("es")

    validate = validator.New()
    es_translations.RegisterDefaultTranslations(validate, trans)

    translateOverride(trans)
}

/**
 * Reemplaza las traducciones predeterminadas de los esquemas de la base de datos.
 */
func translateOverride(trans ut.Translator) {
    validate.RegisterTranslation("required", trans, func(ut ut.Translator) error {
        return ut.Add("required", "{0} debe tener un valor!", true)
    }, func(ut ut.Translator, fe validator.FieldError) string {
        t, _ := ut.T("required", fe.Field())

        return t
    })
}
```

And then in the `main.go` entry function I added `locales.SetupLocales()`. This does not work as expected since the "translation" is being ignored at all.

So, how could I translate error messages by default, without having to validate the struct as the documentation says, or is not possible?:

```golang
err := validate.Struct(user)
    if err != nil {

        errs := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)

        for _, e := range errs {
            // can translate each error one at a time.
            fmt.Println(e.Translate(trans))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example in Go playground : https://go.dev/play/ ? And also clarify what you expect because it's not really clear to me.

Comment: I'd like to override the default translation as a middleware or something, without having to add `validate.Struct()`